# How I can manage Adaptive layout via Autolayout

Tags: ios, ios-autolayout

First of all apologize for the article if it is duplicate.

After a lot of boxing with autolayout I don't get result. I am working on a application that manages on both phone and iPad.

As I implemented design with autolayout in iPhone mode with all trait vary versions when trying to make it in iPad. I am getting this locked scenario. Here is screenshot

[image]

And this is screenshot for iPhone mode:

[image]

I have tried few attempts to correct this but every time I am getting this wierd scenario.

Anyone can suggest me how can I manage this in both device types?

Comment: The best would be to take separate storyboards for iPhone and iPad. Even if get the above working, changes are that you'll again face the similar issue. If you take separate storyboards, it might appear time would be doubled but for such complexity, it actually takes less time.

Comment: That means I can use seperately ok....,But can you tell me why this type of issue happen...?

Comment: Without looking each constraint it would be impossible to reason out. But trust me, instead of finding a fix for this, it would be better to follow what I suggested.

Comment: Ok, I will follow this approach

Comment: Separate Storyboards are easier, but no longer suggested as apps should support multitasking. (Several apps visible next to each other.) Can u share the storyBoard?

Comment: Show an image of your cell on a phone - which, I assume, is how you want it to look. Also show an image of how you *want* it to look on an iPad. Without seeing what you're ***trying*** to do, it's hard to say what you've done wrong. Auto-layout, particularly for table view cells, generally works fine for multiple sizes. Separate storyboards is ***usually*** not a good idea.

Comment: @DonMag I have update my question. Please check it....

Comment: @GouravJoshi - ok... your "DoctorBlogCell" looks the same between sizes... What do you want different with your "HealthBlogCell"?

Comment: @DonMag What the DoctorBlogCell is looking fine...as same I need HealthBlogCell. It both looking fine in iPhone but trying to do in iPad...the HealthBlogCell content is hide...nothing is viewing.....

Comment: @GouravJoshi - if you want it to look the same, why are you changing constraints with Vary for Traits?

Comment: @DonMag I don't understand what the problem is generating.... I do this: remove all constaints for HealthBlog....now it is totally free from all constraints, In iPhone ok, THen I see it in iPad...still all objects showing disabled.....that is getting annoying for me...

Comment: @GouravJoshi - hmm... not sure what you've done to make the objects appear disabled... can you add your storyboard xml source to your question?

Comment: huuhh...after rework from scratch...I finally found what mistake actually happened...Finally I track the pulse....Thanks for discussion......